# I keep getting this error on loading of Interstitial ads

Tags: android, admob

Since I have applied `mInterstitial = null` on destroy - it didn't crash 
error still appears in the log.

How to properly destroy the `mInterstitial`?
there is no `mInterstitial.Destroy`.

`mInterstitial = null` is enough?

The error started since I have integrated Unity ads.

> 10-06 09:21:20.761 3310-4585/? E/Ads: Unable to invokeJavascript
>           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.json.JSONObject com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaiq.zzj(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaiy.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:6)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzajb.zzh(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:3)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaye.onSuccess(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:1)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdda.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:2)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdcq.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:1)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaxs.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:1)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdby.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:39)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdby.addListener(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:11)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaxv.addListener(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:1)
>               at androidx.transition.ViewGroupUtilsApi18.zza(ViewGroupUtilsApi18.java:449)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaiy.zzi(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:7)
>               at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzd.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:30)
>               at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzd.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:39)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbmd.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:7)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbpa.zzp(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:2)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbpl.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:2)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdcq.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:1)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaxs.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:1)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbpm.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:8)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbox.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:1)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcdr.zzf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:2)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdcd.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:2)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdca.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:9)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzddm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:2)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   10-06 09:21:21.011 3310-3310/? E/ViewSystem: ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid.
>
> 10-06 09:23:11.711 3310-4793/? E/Ads: Unable to invokeJavascript
>           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.json.JSONObject com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaiq.zzj(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaiy.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:6)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzajb.zzh(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:3)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaye.onSuccess(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:1)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdda.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:2)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdcq.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:1)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaxs.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:1)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdby.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:39)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdby.addListener(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:11)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaxv.addListener(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:1)
>               at androidx.transition.ViewGroupUtilsApi18.zza(ViewGroupUtilsApi18.java:449)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaiy.zzi(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:7)
>               at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzd.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:30)
>               at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzd.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:39)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbmd.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:7)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbpa.zzp(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:2)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbpl.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:2)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdcq.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:1)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaxs.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:1)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbpm.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:8)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbox.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:1)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcdr.zzf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:2)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdcd.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:2)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdca.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:9)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzddm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.2.0:2)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   10-06 09:23:13.331 3310-3310/? E/UnityMediationAdapter: An ad is already loading for placement ID: admobInterstitialID
>       10-06 09:23:13.331 3310-3310/? E/UnityMediationAdapter: Failed to load Interstitial ad from Unity Ads: INTERNAL_ERROR
>       10-06 09:23:13.451 3310-3389/? E/chromium: [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw

This is my code:

```
mAdView = findViewById(R.id.ad_view);

RequestConfiguration conf = MobileAds.getRequestConfiguration().toBuilder()
        .setTagForChildDirectedTreatment(TAG_FOR_CHILD_DIRECTED_TREATMENT_FALSE)
        .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(TAG_FOR_UNDER_AGE_OF_CONSENT_FALSE)
        .setMaxAdContentRating(MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_G)
        .build();
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(conf);

MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
    }
});


AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();


mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx");

mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded()
    {
        //log interstitial loaded
    }
    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad : errorcode : " + String.valueOf(errorCode));
        super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed()
    {

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        // Ad interstitialAd reLoaded
        Log.d(TAG, "Ad interstitialAd reLoaded");
        super.onAdClosed();
    }
});
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

@Override protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.setAdListener(null);
            if (adscontainerWait != null)
                adscontainerWait.removeAllViews();
            mAdView.destroy();

        }
        mInterstitialAd = null;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you fix it?

Comment: Yes, contacted google admobs support, took them 1 week to find the problem, it was an error on the unity side. google have updated to 18.3.0: Since than , no error on my project. no need to do "mInterstitial = null on destroy". Interstitial clear itselfs.